# How do I eliminate the afterimage when I showback a form?

Tags: codenameone

How do I eliminate the afterimage when I show back a form? Please reference the images below.
Or can I remove the animation of showing back?

Before showback()

[image]

During showback()

[image]

After showback()

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no after image. I'm assuming you changed the UIID of `Form` to a different UIID and didn't make it opaque (bgTransparency = 255) or removed the `bgTransparency` of the `Form` UIID.

In that case the `Form` isn't painted during the transition animation and you see the smearing effect.

Comment: I changed the UIID of the form to 'basefrm' but I already set the bgTransparency = 255. The afterimage issue is only in old device(iPhone7 Plus) during the transition process. That's why I think it is an afterimage because the animation is slow on old devices.
Please refer images in the question .

Comment: In iOS the title area is animated separately which might mean this is triggered by the toolbar area being transparent. Make sure there's an opaque element in the hierarchy there too.

Comment: Do you mean I should set the toolbar to bgTransparency = 255?

Comment: That or another element in the hierarchy e.g the title. Notice you can set the animation mode to slow motion and see what's going on in the simulator.

Comment: Where can I set the animation mode?

Comment: It seems Steve [commented it out](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java#L4307) last year. Not sure why. I'll ask.